# create igraph Graph from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, igraph

I have the following pandas dataframe contains an edgelist as following:

```
        name1              name2    weight
0  $hort, Too  Alexander, Khandi  0.083333
1  $hort, Too             B-Real  0.083333
```

I want to create a igraph object from the pandas dataframe (not from files).
The graph is too large  so I cannot convert it to an adjacency matrix. How to do that?

Answer (score 11):

igraph needs tuples, pandas offers .itertuples() for a pair of:

```
(source, target, weight(optional))
```

Assuming your dataframe is named "df" you can get a directed graph object with weights from a pandas dataframe via:

```
import pandas as pd
import igraph as ig

g = ig.Graph.TupleList(df.itertuples(index=False), directed=True, weights=True, edge_attrs="weight")
```

According to https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#TupleList

> weights - alternative way to specify that the graph is weighted. If
> you set weights to true and edge_attrs is not given, it will be
> assumed that edge_attrs is ["weight"] and igraph will parse the third
> element from each item into an edge weight

So in your case you don't need "edge_attrs=" but I added it just in case for a more general solution.

Comment: Great answer ! I searched long for it. One correction: put weights=False , not True in 
g = ig.Graph.TupleList(df.itertuples(index=False), directed=True, weights=True, edge_attrs="weight")

Otherwise I am getting error

Comment: See example: https://www.kaggle.com/alexandervc/igraph-cheatsheet?scriptVersionId=59716528&cellId=26

Comment: Which error are you getting? The kaggle example does not show any error or a reason to set weight=False (unless you have no weight column in your dataframe of course).

Answer (score 10):

I was also looking for Networkx from_pandas_dataframe's function equivalent in igraph and I found using Graph.TupleList() as the best solution.
so basically you create a tuple from 3 pandas columns and then use this function to create the network.

```
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
Gm = igraph.Graph.TupleList(tuples, directed = True, edge_attrs = ['weight'])
```

Comment: In this case, how do the vertex numbers igraph assigns correspond to the original names from the dataframe?

Comment: Each vertex will be given an attribute called `name` that corresponds to the original names i.e. `name1` and `name2` in your DataFrame. You can get the map of igraph vertex index to names with `{v['name']: v.index for v in list(Gm.vs)}`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using igraph version 0.9.6 and there seems to be a direct way to do this:

```
import igraph as ig
import pandas as pd

mydata = pd.DataFrame({'name1': ['$hort, Too', '$hort, Too'], 
                   'name2': ['Alexander, Khandi', 'B-Real'], 
                   'weight': [0.083333, 0.083333]})
mygraph = ig.Graph.DataFrame(mydata)
```

Comment: I was able to get this work, but had to use mygraph = ig.Graph.DataFrame(mydata, use_vids = False). The use_vids option allows you to use vertex names instead of integers: https://python.igraph.org/en/stable/api/igraph.Graph.html#DataFrame

Answer (score 1):

Just sketching/pseudocode, but what about:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    graph.add_edge(row.name1, row.name2, weight=row.weight)
```

Comment: when I use this code I get this error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'node1'

Comment: @EmmaNej thanks for the heads up. It looks like a tuple is being returned from `iterrows`, so you will want to break apart the tuple. One way is by specifying the index and the row object in the for loop. I updated the example in my answer to reflect that.

Comment: yeah, I tried that also, but still getting error! TypeError: unbound method add_edge() must be called with Graph instance as first argument (got int64 instance instead)

Comment: Ok, well a new error so it looks like igraph has a different add_edge implementation. So I would look up docs for how `graph.add_edge()` works.

I would look at this tutorial: http://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html
Might want to try something like `g.add_edges((2,0))` where `2` and `0` are the ids for the from and to values.

Answer (score 1):

The way I always do this is the following, though I have often repeating edges, which is why my weights are prone to change (I'm assuming your pandas dataframe is named df):

```
import igraph

edgelist = []
weights = []
for i in df.index():
    edge = (df.ix[i, 'name1'], df.ix[i, 'name2'])
    if edge not in edgelist:
        edgelist.append(edge)
        weights.append(1)
    else:
        weights[edgelist.index(edge)] += 1

G = Graph()
G.add_edges(edgelist)
G.es['weight'] = weights
```

Comment: You should drop the parentheses in the line "for i in df.index():"